# Web service server with SOAP on linux

Tags: windows, web-services, soap, ubuntu

I need SOAP web service on Linux that can communicate with a windows web service client (ASP.NET for example). What is the best way to do this? need help!

Can someone give me some examples or some links to some examples that work?

EDIT:
what about c++? I would like to have a c++ web service server. 
how to do it and how to test it from windows (C#?)? please help. 
i did succedded to write a web service with gsoap and wsdl but on windows web service client i have the error :`"the content type text/plain of the response message does not match the content typeof the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). if using a custom encoding be sure that the IsContentTypeSupport is implemented properly."` I don't know what's wrong. The web service is a wsdl url. Can someone light me up?

*The webservice server will be on an ubuntu server!!*

Comment: know that you have found, gSoap you have another problem, using it. Try the documentation: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html or stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsoap (but I see you're there already ;-D)

Comment: what do you mean by using gsoap i will have another problem?

Comment: It's a reference to the “I have a problem. I'll use regular expressions. Now I have two problems” sentence. C++ wouldn't be my pick, but if you're good enough at it, it'll be a bliss. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a soap server in any language you want, more or less:

- PHP, http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php
- Python, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SOAPpy
- C#, using Mono.
- Java, http://oreilly.com/catalog/progwebsoap/chapter/ch03.html
- C++, http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html
- …

The best way is to pick a technology you already know.

Comment: I just had to put the .cgi file inside /cgi-bin. Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Java EE 6 on Glassfish. It's quite simple to deploy from my experience. Check [Java EE 6 Tutorial/Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnayk/index.html)

Comment: i am working on an ubuntu server. I am accessing the server with putty. i am not supposed to use any ide like mono...or anything else.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter - you develop a web service on your local machine. You have to setup an application server (like glassfish, tomcat or whatever technology you use) on your Ubuntu and install your web service which would be probably .war or .ear package. It all can be done by from a command line interface.